# What is the difference between ora_database_name and sys_context('userenv','service_name')

Tags: oracle

What is the difference between ora_database_name and sys_context('userenv','service_name'). 
Both the queries below gives different results.

```
select ora_database_name  from dual;
select sys_context('userenv','service_name') from dual;
```

How and where to find actual database name?

Comment: Those are two different things.Read these concepts to understand the difference between a service and a database  : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/concepts.htm

Answer (score 2):

`ora_database_name` is a synonym to the package function `dbms_standard.database_name`. I suspect it is identical to

```
select sys_context('userenv','db_name') from dual;
```

However, `sys_context('userenv','service_name')` is the service name you are currently using.

A database can support more than one service name. To see the list:

```
SELECT name FROM all_services;
orclpdb1
```

You can add additional services ...

```
EXEC DBMS_SERVICE.CREATE_SERVICE('myservice', 'myservice');
EXEC DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE('myservice', NULL);

SELECT name FROM all_services;
orclpdb1
myservice
```

... which can then be used to connect to the database ...

```
sqlplus user/pass@myhost:1521/myservice
```